# How do I display only two categories Instead of displaying all categories

Tags: categories, dropdown

my plugin code is this

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'hide_empty=0' ); ?>
```

Post Category

thus it display all categories registered

I would like to show only the categories that I want

Comment: Have you read [the Codex entry for `wp_dropdown_categories`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories)?

Comment: yes, but I'm not able to show only the categories I selected by id

he is showing all categories

Would you help me?

Comment: I don't understand where is the problem... Use include argument for wp_dropdown_categories.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done easily using `include` parameter. Check the [documentation of `wp_dropdown_categories()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories). You can pass category id's to `include` parameter as a array.

```
 <?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'include=array( 8,39 )' ); ?>
```